# Optimize XML Reading

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an event that occurs over 50 000 times. Each time this event occurs, I need to go look into an xml file and grab some data. This xml file has over 20 000 possible values.

Before needing to read my xml, the 50 000 event's other work was very fast. As soon as I implemented the xml read, it slowed down the whole operation very significantly.

To read the XML, I am doing this:

```
 XElement xelement = XElement.Load(SomePath);

        IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xelement.Elements();

        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            if (element.Element("SomeNode") == value)
            {
                valueToSet = element.Element("SomeOtherNode").Value
                break;
            }
        }
```

What can I do to optimize this?

Comment: "occurs over 50 000 times" in what timescale? Would it not be worthwhile to pull this XML data into objects once when your application loads, and then queries these objects instead of the XML itself?

Comment: do you need to execute the first two lines every time the event fires, or can you put them in a common container that can be referenced by the foreach when the event fires in order to prevent the first two lings from executing every time the event fires?

Comment: also, why do you need to do a foreach over every element. Is using a find() method on the xml out of the question as opposed to iterating over every element?

Comment: Why is this different from any other performance problem? Find out where it's slow, then speed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should load the file *once*, preprocess it to a `Dictionary<string, String>`, and then just perform a lookup in that dictionary each time the event occurs. You haven't given us enough context to say exactly where you'd cache the dictionary, but that's unlikely to be *particularly* hard.

The loading and converting to a dictionary is really simple:

```
var dictionary = XElement.Load(SomePath)
                         .Elements()
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Element("SomeNode").Value,
                                       x => x.Element("SomeOtherNode").Value);
```

That's assuming that all of the secondary elements contains both a `SomeNode` element and a `SomeOtherNode` element... if that's not the case, you'd need to do some filtering first.

Answer (score 0):

If you always need to load the (refreshed?) file each time, you may want to consider the [XStreamingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx) so that you don't have to load the entire document upfront (as XElement.load does). With XElement.Load, you load the entire XML into memory and then iterate over that. With the XStreaminigElement, you only bring the amount of the document you need into memory. In addition, to then get the first match, use .FirstOrDefault.

If you don't need to constantly refresh the document, consider a caching mechanism like the one @jonskeet offered.